# Issue when uninstalling a service?

Tags: service, windows-server-2012

I am trying to uninstall a recently installed service, I am running this in command line:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>installutil.exe /u "C:\inetpub\www
root\xxx\xxx\xxx.exe"
```

But I am getting this:

```
The uninstall has completed.
An exception occurred while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the
 uninstall will continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalle
d after the uninstall is complete.
```

And this:

```
Removing EventLog source xxx.
An exception occurred during the uninstallation of the System.Diagnostics.EventL
ogInstaller installer.
System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
An exception occurred while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the
 uninstall will continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalle
d after the uninstall is complete.
```

I have no idea where to begin and I really need to uninstall these so any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you have rights to modify the registry on that machine ?

Comment: Yes I have rights to modify the registry

Comment: Try running the command prompt in admin mode.

Comment: Hi i dont know why this worked but when I ran installutil instead of installutil.exe it worked. Thank you for responding to my question

Answer (score 19):

I was facing exact same issue.

The issue is resolved by opening the Command Prompt as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are probably trying to remove a service using a user account which does not have sufficient rights. Specifically, the issue in this case is the removal of some EventLog registry keys during Uninstall.

This may also occur when you are logged in as a user with Administrator privileges yet did not run the Command Prompt in 'Administrator Mode'.

One way to fix this is to make sure that you are running the Command Prompt in Administrator mode. (Right-click > Run as Administrator)

I have also encountered some cases where this method still fails to solve the *SecurityException* problem due to some registry keys not having 'Full Control' permissions for Administrator accounts.

The following keys should have 'Full Control' set for Administrators in order for the service to be able to write to the EventLog:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application

This may be done by:

1. Invoking the Windows Registry Editor

   - Run [Win + R]
   - Type 'regedit'
   - OK
2. Navigate a path listed about
3. Right click on the desired path
4. Make sure that both *Read* and *Full Control* permission checkboxes are ticked for Administrators
5. Click *Apply* and *OK*
6. Repeat the same process for the other path